# Curl container command into c#

Tags: c#, curl, balena

I'm trying to pass the following restart command that will run in a container, into a C# command, but I'm not sure how to do it, help please:

```
curl --header "Content-Type:application/json" "$BALENA_SUPERVISOR_ADDRESS/v2/applications/$BALENA_APP_ID/restart-service?apikey=$BALENA_SUPERVISOR_API_KEY" -d '{"serviceName": "venue"}'
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at HttpClient?

Comment: yes but I'm not sure how to implement it with the balena and json, I understand the -d '{"serviceName": "venue"}' is the task but not how to implement the rest

Comment: Take a look at the curl docs and `-d` specifies the content of a POST request which matches the `Content-Type` header which is also specified.

Comment: Would this be enought? `using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), "http://$BALENA_SUPERVISOR_ADDRESS/v2/applications/$BALENA_APP_ID/restart-service?apikey=$BALENA_SUPERVISOR_API_KEY/"))
    {
        request.Content = new StringContent("{\"serviceName\": \"venue\"}");
        request.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json"); 

        var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
    }
} `

Comment: I'm just not sure if `"$BALENA_SUPERVISOR_ADDRESS/v2/applications/$BALENA_APP_ID/restart-service?apikey=$BALENA_SUPERVISOR_API_KEY"` should go into http

Comment: Yeah, you're going to need to do some extra work to get these values replaced.

Comment: Also consider using `HttpClient.PostAsync` and `JsonContent.Create(new {ServiceName = "venue")` instead of hand-crafting JSON.